# Translucent effect in css or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been searching for some CSS or jQuery that will achieve a translucent effect. Most of what I've seen are people using translucent as a synonym for transparent, and that's not really accurate or what I'm trying to get.

I would like a box and when this box passes over objects, it distorts the objects underneath. Think a bathroom window. It allows light to pass through, but not a clear picture. I've attached an image showing what I want to achieve.

My thinking is I would apply this effect on the top image (the white box in the sample image) but it might possibly be something else. Also, I'm pretty sure this will be javascript but I'm including CSS as an option in case there's something out there I didn't know could produce this type of thing.

[image]

Comment: you can use the canvas and compute the result. This effect will not be done natively. Look for a glass effect algorithm

Comment: The only thing I can think of off the top of my head would be to use a translucent .png image as the background for the box...

Comment: See my answer below for a solution using images and css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As been suggested:

1. If you only need the effect to appear over an image (and not on top of html text etc.)
2. The number of images the effect should appear over is limited

Then you could prepare an alternate version of each image with the translucent effect applied, then use the alternate image inside the effect box as background image, where the background-position is calculated based on the box position.

Or you could look into this more complicated way: http://abduzeedo.com/ios7-frosted-glass-effect-html-5-and-javascript

Answer (score 3):

Just use a transparent PNG, especially if you need a texture like your example.

Otherwise you can set the `opacity` of the inner div to some value < 1

Comment: I have tried using that method already, but the problem I run into is the visibility of the textured png when it's not over any objects. Like sitting on a white background you can still see the texture. I think this is going to have to be something like jQuery listens to the scroll and checks the objects underneath, applying some effect to them where they overlap.

Comment: Opacity affects the transparency of the background, and does not create a translucent effect.

Comment: There's no way to do this without opacity or a transparent PNG. I suggest using the PNG, and clipping the "hover" element to the parent picture's borders. Set `overflow: hidden` on a div wrapping the photo and make the inner div a child element. That way it's never visible outside the div

Comment: I'm not saying I can't or won't use opacity, I realize that's going to go into the effect. What I'm saying is opacity alone won't get it.

Answer (score 0):

An extention of the idea proposed by  @Dryden Long

Here is a working Example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X2TCC/)

You can create a **translucent** version of the image in GIMP/photoshop. Then set the css background property of the child div to fixed:

```
.parent-div {
     position:relative;
     background: url(normal.png) no-repeat 0 0 ;
}

.child-div {
   width: 100px;
   height:100px;
   background: url(distorted.png) no-repeat <X> <Y> ; /* x y relative to the parent*/
   background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative to the `opacity` or `translucent image` solutions listed in the other answers. You could try using a CSS3 `filter` with `blur` effect:

```
img {
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
    filter: blur(10px);
}
```

Please note however, that this is still in the **experimental** phase and subject to change. It also may note be supported by all browser vendors. For a list of compatible browsers, check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility).

[This](http://caniuse.com/css-filters) list from *CanIUse* may also be helpful for you to look at.

In addition, [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/say-hello-to-css3-filters/) is another good resource on CSS Filters.

Comment: Do you know how to get this to affect the overlapping part of the top box and the object below? Setting this value on the top box distorts the top box, and not the object below.

Comment: @o_O Hmm, not sure right off hand. I've actually never used CSS Filters before. Read a lot about them though and seen them used. Seemed like something that might work for you. I'll try to mock something up in a fiddle. Let me get back to you on that one.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a good candidate is the jQuery Blur plugin. Seems to do exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks for everyone's suggestions.

http://www.blurjs.com/